# How to set input type date with 100% width in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a web application using jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 and I'm interested in using a `<input type="date" />` with 100% width but there's a [gap](http://jsfiddle.net/dcardoso/sLrrc/) (the space where it was supposed to have the arrow is cutted) when viewing the page on iOS4.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't show any gap. can you post a screenshot or give a clear description?

Comment: Add a `reset.css` to your styles. Best one will be Eric Meyer's Reset CSS. Should do the fix. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar I've tried using [Eric Meyer's Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) but the issue remains.

Comment: Oh okay... :) It seems to be something like a spin-button issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution to resolve that is by adding the following CSS to overide the default browser CSS:

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,  
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {  
    -webkit-appearance: none;  
    margin: 0;  
}
```